# Rails undefined method count

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to check that an address isn't being used before I delete it. My code is as follows:

```
def destroy
        @address = current_user.addresses.find_by_id(params[:id])
        redirect_to user_addresses_path(current_user) if @address.nil?

        if Organisation.find_by_address_id(params[:id]).count == 0 && Event.find_by_address_id(params[:id]).count == 0
            @address.destroy
            redirect_to user_addresses_path(current_user)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Cannot delete address because it is being used"
            redirect_to user_addresses_path(current_user)
        end
    end
```

however, this gives me an error:

```
undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: address_id is an index on both tables, if that is of any relevance.

Comment: Please only tag your questions with language tags please. This is so we can keep tagspam on Stack Overflow to a minimum. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I thought they were relevant to my query. Lesson learnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Organisation.find_by_address_id(params[:id])` will return a single object, or `nil` if one without that `address_id` does not exist.

Perhaps you meant `Organisation.find_all_by_address_id(params[:id])`.